# automatically select option if only one in selectbox list - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700356/filtering-a-select-list-via-input-box-jquery) as a way to filter a select box.  I want to extend it so that if there is only one option left it is automatically selected.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($j('#selectList option:visible').length == 1) {
    $j('#selectList option:visible').attr('selected', true);
}
```