# Results by demographic group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a web app that aggregates results from a survey. In the survey, each survey respondent selects their gender and age range (ex. Male, 18-30). The respondent then answers two questions regarding their interest in a topic (each on a scale of 1-100).

I'd like the user of the web app to be able to cut the survey results by various demographic combinations. For example, if the user would like to see the average score for each question among Male, 18-30 year-olds, they would select Male from one select box and 18-30 from a second select box.

I have been able to get a list of scores associated with all combinations for age and gender, using this method:

```
def averagedemo_score
    scores.select("AVG(scoreone) as avg_demoscoreone, AVG(scoretwo) as avg_demoscoretwo, gender").group("gender", "age")
end
```

and this in my controller:

```
@demogenagescore = @athlete.averagedemo_score.to_a.sort_by{|e| e[:gender]}
```

The problem I'm having is creating a way to only display the scores that correspond to what has been selected in the select boxes. As an example, the code for the first select box is:

```
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select([[''],['Male'],['Female']], :selected => :gender) %>
```

Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you require additional information. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at some jQuery methods for doing this client side such as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700356/filtering-a-select-list-via-input-box-jquery

Comment: You could have wrote this question in a much better way, generalizing it. This way is too localized.